# power bi service browser looks strange and empty

Tags: powerbi

Hi I am new to Power Bi.
After creating a report in Power BI Desktop I am trying to publish it. I get a Success message.

[image]

When I following the link ("Open 'Skedulering2019.pbix in Power BI"), however I get a strange looking browser (not the same as in any tutorial I have seen). Also I cannot see anything loaded. What am I missing.?

[image]

Regards

Comment: I'm 98% sure that you can solve the problem by switching to Chrome.

Comment: I get a message :  The web browser couldn't be launched. Please make sure that a program to open HTTP URLs is set in the windows default programs dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do

1. Wait for few mins, sometimes I have seen a lag , when I do publish from Desktop and representation in the Web
2. Switch to Google Browser

Regards,

Kunal Kumar Shah

Comment: Thank you. I have tried both. But still the unfamiliar browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using an unsupported version of Internet Explorer. 
Here's a list browsers that PowerBI supports as of June 2018:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-browser-support